# How to send a POST request with JavaScript XMLlhttpRequest to Google App Engine?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest

I would like to send a JavaScript XMLlhttpRequest to a .py script on Google App Engine. **But I am not looking for a `jQuery` solution**

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:sendMessage();">
    <b>User:</b>
    <input value="" name="user" id="user">
    <br>
    <b>Comment here:</b>
    <div>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var url = window.location.href;
    var element_id = "my_first_element";

    function sendMessage() {
        console.log("working?");
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                "status: " + xhr.status +
                "<br />statusText: " + xhr.statusText +
                "<br />server response: <br />" + xhr.responseText;
            }
        }

        xhr.open("POST", "communication.py", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("url=" + encodeURI(url) +
                 "&user=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('user').innerHTML) +
                 "&message=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById('message').innerHTML) +
                 "&element_id=" + encodeURI(element_id)
                 );
    }

</script>
```

Google App Engine (script file is called communication.py and is in home directory of my GAE app):

```
class CommentsService(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """This Handler is responsible for the Commenting Service"""

    def post(self):

    comment = Comments()

    user = cgi.escape(self.request.get('user'))
    message = cgi.escape(self.request.get('message'))

    comment.url_ = cgi.escape(self.request.get('url'))
    comment.user_ = cgi.escape(self.request.get('user'))
    #comment.date = cgi.escape(self.request.get('date'))
    comment.message = cgi.escape(self.request.get('message'))
    comment.element_id = cgi.escape(self.request.get('element_id'))

    comment.put()

    self.response.out.write("input1: %s<br />input2: %s" % (user, message))
```

app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

I got the error messsage in the console:

> POST http://myapp.appspot.com/communication.py 404 (Not Found)

Therefore, I guess there is some issue with finding communication.py

Any ideas why the file is not found?

Comment: What's in your app.yaml, and do you have a webapp2.WSGIApplication routing /communication.py to your handler?

Comment: added app.yaml to the question. yes, i got routing sorted

Comment: Your app.yaml is sending requests to myapp.application - what does that look like? Having a URL with .py on the end is technically fine, but is unusual, and makes me suspect you're expecting it to match the URL with the filename automatically. That isn't how it works.

Comment: myapp.application is required by GAE by default if I'm not mistaken. This is one of my .py scripts(the first one which was created at the very begining). I would like to send the form data to communication.py for processing(database update).

Comment: You're mistaken, you should probably check the getting started guide that will explain this kind of thing: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Comment: Sorry, I've read the part about the form handling and I'm still confused. My handler in myapp.py is mapped like this: `('/comments_admin', communication.CommentsService)`. I don't get why it doesn't find communication.py. Should I add a new part to the app.yaml like `script: communication.application` ? Is it possible to have several handling scripts in the same directory, or there should a separate directory for each handling script?

Comment: If you've mapped /comments_admin, then you should be making the request to that URL instead of /communication.py

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what was already suggested by Greg:

Change handlers in app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: /communication
  script: app.communication
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application
```

Changes in communication.py:

```
class CommentsService(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """This Handler is responsible for the Commenting Service"""

    def post(self):
        comment = Comments()

        user = cgi.escape(self.request.get('user'))
        message = cgi.escape(self.request.get('message'))

        comment.url_ = cgi.escape(self.request.get('url'))
        comment.user_ = user
        #comment.date = cgi.escape(self.request.get('date'))
        comment.message = message
        comment.element_id = cgi.escape(self.request.get('element_id'))

        comment.put()

        self.response.out.write("input1: %s<br />input2: %s" % (user, message))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/communication', CommentsService)],
                              debug=True)
```